# Saving file to App_Data doesn't seem to work when app is uploaded to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, sendgrid

I have a small MVC 5 app, and the point is that it works all fine in my localhost, but when I publish it to Azure, some parts doesn't work. For example, I have something like this in my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
       <div style="position:relative;">
            <label>Image</label>
            <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">
            Choose a file...
            <input type="file" name="Image" accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
                      style="position:absolute;z-index:2;top:0;left:0;filter: alpha(opacity=0); opacity:0;background-color:transparent;color:transparent;"
                       onchange='$("#upload-image-info").html($(this).val());' />
           </a>
           <span class="label label-info" id="upload-image-info"></span>
       </div>
</div>
```

So, then in my server side I have something like this:

```
    public ActionResult ServiceRequest(RequestViewModel rvm, HttpPostedFileBase image = null, HttpPostedFileBase video = null)
    {
        tmpPicturePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/Images");
        tmpVideoPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/Videos");

        // I check for some properties, and then save the file
        filename = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
        imagePath = Path.Combine(tmpPicturePath, filename);
        image.SaveAs(imagePath);

        // Afterwards, I give the imagePath to SendGrid for attachment to a mail
        message.AddAttachment(imagePath);

        // And later in code, I send the mail
        transportWeb.Deliver(message);
     }
```

Please note that I omitted some parts of my code above, to make it more clear about what I want to do. The point is that in my localhost, it works fine, I am able to select a file and after uploading it, sends it via e-mail. But, when I publish the website on Azure, and try the same thing, when I press the button it seems like it is uploading the file, but afterwards I get an error message saying:

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request.

I don't know whether it cannot store the files on server, or cannot read them afterwards for attachment, or cannot send the mail. Any idea about what the problem may be?

Comment: Azure is a cloud platform.  When you deploy to one of the azure servers, you are not guaranteed that it will remain on that same server.  If a file is not part of your publish package, such as a user uploading a file to your site, it can/may/will be deleted if your site moves to another server.  All this to say, you should really be using Azure Blob Storage for saving files uploaded to your website as local storage is not permanent.  More info - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected to the FTP server and manually created the folders, which worked okay.

Comment: You can use `Directory.CreateDirectory(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"/App_Data/"));` so that the directory is created in case it doesn't exist